# my Flask python server still running after shutdown

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

I Tried running a new http://127.0.0.1:5000/ local server and the old one was still showing after I stopped it and hard reload.
my Chorme still show pervious server results after I've ended the program and when I ran another program it shows same result as old one.

Comment: How are you shutting down the server? From CLI?

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL or SQLite?

Comment: Are you saying that you change your code but the result stays the same? (This isn't your server still running, its basically your browser caching some pages / files) Do a hard refresh in your browser, it is usually "CTRL" + "F5"

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular it was because i started getting the problem when i started looking with SQLite

Comment: @iohans No with the IDE stop button

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I already tried that

Comment: @Fabian If you think that's relevant then you should explain it in your question. How are we supposed to guess what's relevant in your tags if you don't explain it properly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just change sever port from 5000 to 8000 for new program

#Add host="localhost", port=8000

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

> This way:

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="localhost", port=8000, debug=True)
```

Comment: wouldn't be best to implement a shutdown?

Comment: @nbk I already did that didn't work

Comment: Why not upload your script to GitHub or reduce your code example to the minimum, you have a problem but we can't help without your code